# How to export an enum from a module so it can be imported and resolved at runtime

Tags: typescript, enums

I have the following enum in a shared module called "common":

```
export enum TranslationValue {
  VH = -2,
  VL = 1,
  Neutral = 0,
  AL = 1,
  AH = 2,
  NA = "NA",
  IR = "IR"
}
```

When I compile this with the option `declaration: true` I get the following in the output d.ts file:

```
export declare enum TranslationValue {
    VH = -2,
    VL = 1,
    Neutral = 0,
    AL = 1,
    AH = 2,
    NA = "NA",
    IR = "IR"
}
```

Then a different package uses this shared module and gives me a runtime error:

> Attempted import error: 'TranslationValue' is not exported from '@gemini/common'

What is the problem here? I understand that the `declare` keyword means that I'm basically telling the compiler that the enum will be defined somewhere else at runtime, but I don't know how to get around that. I do not want to re-define the enum anywhere. I just want it to be exported so that it can be and imported and used directly from the common module.

Here's what I used for my tsconfig:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": ["esnext"],
    "target": "esnext",
    "strict": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true
    "declaration": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "rootDir": "src",
    "sourceMap": true
  }
}
```